# My variables are not initializing properly

Tags: java, variables

In my code below `double getAirSpeed` `double calcPatternwidth` and `double calcPatternLength` are not being initialized properly, why?

```
/**
 * holding patterns
 * assignment 1 
 * question 2 
 **/ 

import java.util.Scanner; 

public class StockiColeA1Q2  {

  public static void main(String []args)  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double getAirSpeed ;
    double calcPatternWidth;
    double calcPatternLength; 

    System.out.println("That speed is " + getAirSpeed + 
                       "\nHolding pattern width: " + calcPatternWidth +
                       "kms\nHolding pattern length: " + calcPatternLength + "kms");  

  }//main 

  public static double getAirSpeed() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Enter the speed in Knots: "); 
      double knots = keyboard.nextDouble(); //knots given by user 

      return knots*1.852;

  }//get air speed 

  public static double calcPatternWidth(double knots) {

  return (knots/60*Math.PI)*2;

  }//patern width 

  public static double calcPatternLength(double knots) {

    return knots/60 + (knots/60*Math.PI)*2;


  }//pattern width 

}//class
```

Comment: What's the question? What's the expected output? What do you get, any error? Please clarify it in the question BODY (not title). Also, add tags to your question, specially the language of the code.

Comment: you declare them, then don't do anything with them. So there's your answer: if you want anything *in* them, you have to first make your code do that.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't properly initializing the variables in main. You show call the functions and assign them up front and then display them. I think what you were looking for was a `main` that looked liked this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double getAirSpeed = getAirSpeed();
    double calcPatternWidth = calcPatternWidth(getAirSpeed);
    double calcPatternLength = calcPatternLength(getAirSpeed);

    System.out.println("That speed is " + getAirSpeed + "\nHolding pattern width: " + calcPatternWidth
            + "kms\nHolding pattern length: " + calcPatternLength + "kms");

}// main
```

The code above uses the `getAirSpeed` as a parameter to `calcPatternWidth` and `calcPatternLength`. I am guessing that was what you intended to accomplish.

You really should close the Scanner object when finished so I'd amend `getAirSpeed()` to call `keyboard.close()` before returning.

```
public static double getAirSpeed() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the speed in Knots: ");
    double knots = keyboard.nextDouble(); // knots given by user

    keyboard.close();
    return knots * 1.852;

}// get air speed
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am not able to see where you are initializing the given variables. As all three vairables are local to main method so compiler will not assign the default value to them. just creating getter of those variable will not assign the value. If you create the variable out side the main method in class the compiler will assign the defaut value but you have to make them static as main method is static and you cannot use non-static variable inside the static block.